# create MySQL DB from netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

I am following the netbeans tutorial on using hibernate ( http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html ). Under section `Creating the Database` , step 2 says:

```
After installing the plugin, start the MySQL database by expanding
the Databases node in the Services window, right-clicking the
MySQL Server node and choosing Start.
```

But there is no such `start` option in my Netbeans 7.2. In fact the MySQL database is actually `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [myname on Default schema]`. And while it lists my existing databases, there is no way to execute steps 2 to 4 that the tutorial requires. I am using XAMPP for MySQL. And I have Mac OS X Lion 10.8.

For example, how do I even get to a `Create MySQL database` dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another tutorial that promises to help configure MySQL inside Netbeans: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html. I think it has the answers I sought.